# Why the object lifetime ends before non-trivial destructor execution?

Tags: c++, object, destructor, lifetime

I am confused because I found some information about lifetime of object in C++:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime

> For any object of class types whose destructor is not trivial,
>   lifetime ends when the execution of the destructor begins.

1. **Why**, is there any rationale?
2. If that means **I shouldn't do this**?

   ```
   #include <iostream>

   class Foo {
   public:
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(const Foo&) = default;
    ~Foo() { std::cout << member; }

    int member = 666;
   };

   int main() {
     Foo a;
   }
   ```

Comment: Ok, could you answer to me? I didn't find answer to my questions in link you added.

Comment: The argument is symmetry.   The lifetime of an object begins when construction is finished.   Since destruction is logically a reverse sequence of construction, this means lifetime ends when the destructor starts.     Your example is valid - the lifetime of members begins before execution of the constructor body, and ends after execution of the destructor.

Comment: Thanks @Peter ;)